# Should I use a class to define functions that will use the same arguments, or should I use global variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, apologies if the question has already been answered somewhere, I have not managed to find an answer to my question, but I am fairly new to the use of stackoverflow.

I am trying to optimize some code, and I would like to do it the "right" way. I have a function A that does pre-processing and defines some variables that will be used by another function B. Now, I cannot define those variables directly in B because I want to avoid repeating the processing step. I could pass on the variables as arguments to the function B, but to simplify this I would like to avoid this.

One option would of course be to use global variables, but I read in multiple places that this is a bad habit, one of the reason being that it breaks encapsulation.

An alternative that I could see would be to define a class (some sort of a master class) in which I put all the functions to use and pass the "self" for accessing the variables. Does anyone have some arguments against this? Is this also a bad approach for some reason?

Thank you in advance to anyone who has some element of response !

Comment: That is hard to say without knowing more about some details. Will the results only be used by function B? Then I think returning them and handing them in as arguments is the right way. Do they represent some kind of state, that A and B are related to? Maybe a class is the right way. Globals are (almost) always not the way to go, except in very specific cases.

Comment: It's pretty easy to generalize: the answer to "should I use global variables" is usually "no."

Comment: @L3viathan Thank you for taking the time to reply. Indeed, I should maybe give more context. Let's say that I have a file that does simulations of astrophysical objects. This code already contains classes and functions. When looking at the structure of the code, I feel like I could put everything in a new class (thus treating the whole simulation as an object) that would contain the already defined classes and functions for the different elements of the simulations. My question is: does this seam heretic to you, or would that not be so absurd after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `self` is the best approach. I guess your case is something similar to this.

```
class DemoClass:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def fun1(self): 
        print(self.name)

    def fun2(self):
        print(self.age)
```

Here you can access the variables as self (instance of class) is passed.